# MongoImport only new data from file

Tags: mongodb, file, mongoimport

Yesterday, I used mongoimport cmd to import new file(a.json - 1GB) in my mongodb.
But today, new data arrived to a.json and now we have modified version of a.json(3GB).
Now, I just want to add **only +1GB data** in my MongoDB.

How can I insert only new data documents(column or row)?

Comment: See [`--mode insert|upsert|merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-mode) in the documentation or even `mongoimport --help` It really depends on what you want to do, but as long as `_id` is unique or not even supplied it will just insert to the new collection with mode `insert`. Read the options though because you might just want one of the other ones. Also `insert` is the "default" mode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`mongoimport -d database --file collection`

or

`mongoimport -d database --file collection --mode=insert`

Default mode is `insert`.